# Relationship between two harmonic conjugates

Tags: complex-analysis

Say given the function $u(x,y)$ we have two harmonic conjugates for $u$, which are $v$, $w$ such that:

$f: x+iy \mapsto u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$

$g: x+iy \mapsto u(x,y) + iw(x,y)$

Then what is the said relationship between $v$, $w$?

I am inclined to believe that $v, w$ only defers by a constant function $\Phi(x) $ since for both $v,w$ we have $v,w = \int u_x dy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set

$\lambda(z) = f(z) - g(z); \tag{1}$

then $\lambda(z)$ being the difference of holomorphic functions, is itself holomorphic, and we see that

$\Re(\lambda(z)) = 0; \tag{2}$

We thus have

$\lambda(z) = i\phi(x, y), \tag{3}$

where

$\phi(x, y) = v(x, y) - w(x, y); \tag{4}$

The Cauchy-Riemann equations now imply that

$\phi_x = \phi_y = 0, \tag{5}$

that is,

$\nabla \phi = 0; \tag{6}$

assuming the domain of $f$ and $g$ is a connected set in $\Bbb C$, it follows that

$\phi = c \tag{7}$

is a real constant.  Thus

$v - w = c, \tag{8}$

or

$v = w + c. \tag{9}$

That's how I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us where these functions are defined. I'll just assume they are defined on $\mathbb C.$  Then the entire function $f-g$ has real part equal to $0$ everwhere. Therefore $f-g$ is a purely imaginary constant.